# Basic Lie group Theory

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, topological-groups

I have a couple of clarifying questions about Lie groups. (In particular matrix Lie groups)

1. when we say a closed subgroup of a Lie group G, do we literally mean closed in the usual topological sense of being closed (same with compact?)
2. when we say a lie subgroup of a Lie group G, do we mean a subgroup that has a manifold structure (versus a subgroup which wouldn't?)
3. path connected = connected in a matrix subgroup?

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. Closed in the usual (topological) sense.
2. A subgroup which is also a submanifold.
3. Yes, these are the same because every manifold is locally path connected.